# Using the sequential model with Recurrent Neural Networks

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I've been working with a recurrent neural network implementation with the Keras framework and, when building the model i've had some problems.

> Keras 2.2.4
>
> Tensorflow 1.14.0

My model consists in only three layers: Embeddings, Recurrent and a Dense layer. It currently looks like this:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(input_dim=vocab_size, output_dim= EMBEDDING_DIM, input_length= W_SIZE))
if MODEL == 'GRU':
    model.add(CuDNNGRU(NUM_UNITS))
if MODEL == 'RNN':
    model.add(SimpleRNN(NUM_UNITS))
if MODEL == 'LSTM':
    model.add(CuDNNLSTM(NUM_UNITS))
model.add(Dense(vocab_size, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])
```

What I'm trying to do this is add the `return_state=True` to the recurrent layers in order to get those states when I use the `model.predict()` function but, when i add it, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: All layers in a Sequential model should have a single output tensor. For multi-output layers, use the functional API.
```

I've tried using the TimeDistributed wrapper layer around the Dense layer, but it didn't change anything.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Sequential API is designed for straight-forward models that goes like a chain. That is, output of one layer connected to the next and so on.

So if you want multiple outputs out, you need the Keras Functional API.

```
from tensorflow.keras import layers, models

inp = layers.Input(shape=(n_timesteps,))
out = layers.Embedding(input_dim=vocab_size, output_dim= EMBEDDING_DIM, input_length= n_timesteps)(inp)
if MODEL == 'GRU':
    out, state = layers.CuDNNGRU(NUM_UNITS, return_state=True)(out)
if MODEL == 'RNN':
    out, state = layers.SimpleRNN(NUM_UNITS, return_state=True)(out)
if MODEL == 'LSTM':
    out, state = layers.CuDNNLSTM(NUM_UNITS, return_state=True)(out)
out = layers.Dense(vocab_size, activation='softmax')(out)
model = models.Model(inputs=inp, outputs=[out, state])
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])
model.summary()
```